# Не выходит форматировать дату

Tags: база-данных, sqlite

Делаю запрос к бд, что бы узнать количество дней в заданном месяце:

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT date('%q-%q-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');", year, month);
```

Получаю ответ (для примера): ***2005-02-28***. Как оставить только количество дней?В хелпе указано что можно использовать strftime() как альтернативу с указанным форматом.
Пробовал еще так, но не вышло:

```
char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT strftime('%d','%q-%q-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day');", year, month);
```

Comment: Akina, такая функция есть в sqlite?

Comment: Упс... увлёкся, не посмотрел пристально на диалект, извиняюсь...

Comment: *Пробовал еще так, но не вышло* А проверьте `SELECT strftime('%d', date('%q-%q-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day'));`

Comment: @Akina, char *sql = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', date('2006-02-01','start of month','+1 month','-1 day'));");  - пытаюсь сделать для примера так и получаю в ответ: "SQL error: unrecognized token: " ' ".

Comment: Извиняюсь, был не внимателен с sqlite3_mprintf, всё заработало